# How to return NULL and not an Exception with Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb

If I pass an invalid row, it throws an exception. I would like it to return NULL so I can use it to further process the rest of my scripts.

```
module_id = module_id

mongo_document = mongo_collection.find_one({ '_id': '%s' % module_id}, { '_id':0, 'svn_path':1 })
myvar = mongo_document
for key, value in myvar.iteritems():
    print value
```

Comment: catch the `Exception`?

Comment: Which exception is actually being raised? it looks like `find_one` might return `None` already if no matching collections are found. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/collection.py#L601, is `myvar` `None`? and you are trying to call `iteritems` on `None`?

Comment: I'm an idiot, you're right it does return none. I didnt check for this, I went ahead and attempted to print the value without checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your problem isn't in the find_one function. when you ask for a value that doesnt exist its returns a None value to python, my guess that your exception is actually in the for loop. so i would do something like that:

```
module_id = module_id

mongo_document = mongo_collection.find_one({ '_id': '%s' % module_id}, { '_id':0, 'svn_path':1 })
myvar = mongo_document
if myvar is not None:
   for key, value in myvar.iteritems():
       print value
eilf:
   print "sorry i could find that id"
```

Comment: yea that was it, I forgot to check `myvar`

Comment: Yep, i have to wait a few more mins.